# How to write a LINQ to return results only if value is present in a pre-definded list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a LINQ query to fetch a query result only if a value is within a pre defined list value.

But getting the following exception

```
The LINQ expression 'Where<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity>, EmployerEntity>>(
source: Join<TransparentIdentifier<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity>, EmployerEntity, int, TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity>, EmployerEntity>>(
    outer: Join<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity, Nullable<int>, TransparentIdentifier<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity>>(
        outer: DbSet<EmployeeBenefit>, 
        inner: DbSet<EmployeeEntity>, 
        outerKeySelector: (e) => e.EmployeeEntityCntr, 
        innerKeySelector: (e0) => (Nullable<int>)e0.EmployeeEntityCntr, 
        resultSelector: (e, e0) => new TransparentIdentifier<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity>(
            Outer = e, 
            Inner = e0
        )), 
    inner: DbSet<EmployerEntity>, 
    outerKeySelector: (ti) => ti.Inner.EmployerEntityCntr, 
    innerKeySelector: (e1) => e1.EmployerEntityCntr, 
    resultSelector: (ti, e1) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<EmployeeBenefit, EmployeeEntity>, EmployerEntity>(
        Outer = ti, 
        Inner = e1
    )), 
predicate: (ti0) => ti0.Outer.Outer.EmployeeCntr == (Unhandled parameter: __iEmployeeID_0) && !(ti0.Outer.Outer.EndDate.HasValue) || ti0.Outer.Outer.EndDate >= (Nullable<DateTime>)DateTime.Now && ti0.Outer.Outer.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && ti0.Outer.Outer.CarRego == (Unhandled parameter: __registration_1) && Any<Benefit>(
    source: (Unhandled parameter: ___benefitCodes_2), 
    predicate: (b) => b.Code == ti0.Outer.Outer.BenefitCode))' 

could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

If i remove the below condition from the LINQ query, the query works without error

**&& _benefitCodes.Any(b => b.Code == employeeBenefit.BenefitCode)**

Could you please tell me what i'm missing here

LINQ Query:

```
 _benefitCodes = new List<Benefit>(){
                new Benefit() { Name = "Maitenance", Code = "AAAAA" },
                new Benefit() { Name = "Maitenance", Code = "BBBBB" }
            };

currentBudgets = (from employeeBenefit in _context.EmployeeBenefit
                                  join employeeEntity in _context.EmployeeEntity
                                  on employeeBenefit.EmployeeEntityCntr equals employeeEntity.EmployeeEntityCntr
                                  join employerEntity in _context.EmployerEntity
                                  on employeeEntity.EmployerEntityCntr equals employerEntity.EmployerEntityCntr
                                  where employeeBenefit.EmployeeCntr == iEmployeeID
                                  && (!employeeBenefit.EndDate.HasValue || employeeBenefit.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
                                  && employeeBenefit.StartDate <= DateTime.Now
                                  && employeeBenefit.CarRego == registration
                                  && _benefitCodes.Any(b => b.Code == employeeBenefit.BenefitCode)
                                  select new BenefitCurrentBudget
                                  {
                                      Cntr = employeeBenefit.Cntr,
                                      BenefitCode = employeeBenefit.BenefitCode,
                                      PaymentFrequencyCode = employeeBenefit.PaymentFrequencyCode,
                                      InstalmentAmount = employeeBenefit.InstalmentAmt,
                                      TotalAmount = employeeBenefit.TotalAmt,
                                      CarRego = employeeBenefit.CarRego,
                                      ApprovedFlag = employeeBenefit.ApprovedFlag
                                  }).ToList();

I need values from the query result where the result has employeeBenefit.BenefitCodes only from the pre-defined list _benefitCodes.Code
```

Comment: check my answer if it helps, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the only cause of error is the `_benefitCodes.Any(b => b.Code == employeeBenefit.BenefitCode)`, try this

```
var onlyCodes = _benefitCodes.Select(x => x.Code).ToList();
```

And change your `_benefitCodes.Any(b => b.Code == employeeBenefit.BenefitCode)`
to

```
&& onlyCodes.Contains(employeeBenefit.BenefitCode)
```

what `Linq` error is telling you that it cannot convert your query build up and if you are sure that if you removed `_benefitCodes.Any(b => b.Code == employeeBenefit.BenefitCode)` it is working, then it cannot translate that query.